# No exported member 'SignaturePadModule' / Cannot find module 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, signaturepad

[image]

Im trying to build an APK of this ionic project im working on. I already installed and updated the import but this still shows. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome! Can you please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: Since 'Can somebody help me?' is not really a question by our community's standards, could you please [read about why](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541) and apply what you learn to ask your question? You can also see [ask] for further guidance.

Comment: Hello i am sorry im new here

Comment: No worries! Just take the time to read the guidance materials I linked you to, and apply what you learn to ([edit] and) improve your question post to meet community quality standards.

Comment: Note: I think you should also read about [when and when not to comment](/help/privileges/comment).